# Google Map and Google Geocode Service returning different lat & lng for same address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing weird issue with google geocode API Service. I am requesting 
**"48 spottiswoode residences, spottiwood park, Singapore 088660"** address for which API is returning lat = 1.345871 and lng = 103.75089739999999 respectively. 
But, Google Map showing lat = 1.2752757 and lng = 103.8346363 for the same address.

Request URL:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sSingapore%2C%20088660&7sUS&8m2&1scountry&2sSingapore&9sen-US&callback=*xdc*._wo127a&token=117480](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sSingapore%2C%20088660&7sUS&8m2&1scountry&2sSingapore&9sen-US&callback=_xdc_._wo127a&token=117480)

Response:

```
{ "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Singapore",
               "short_name" : "Singapore",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bukit Batok",
               "short_name" : "Bukit Batok",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Singapore",
               "short_name" : "Singapore",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Singapore",
               "short_name" : "SG",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Singapore, Singapore",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 1.345871,
               "lng" : 103.7508974
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 1.347219980291502,
                  "lng" : 103.7522463802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 1.344522019708498,
                  "lng" : 103.7495484197085
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJOfDA4T8Q2jERL48IW_56xww",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The provided address doesn't seem to be correct(the correct address is **48 Spottiswoode Park Road, Singapur 088660**)

To get results similar too maps.google.com(even with wrong addresses) you rather should use a [`Places.TextSearch`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) :

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function init() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 19
  });

  var request = {
    query: '48 spottiswoode residences, spottiwood park, Singapore 088660'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var ll = results[0].geometry.location;
      new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: ll
      });
      
      map.setCenter(ll);
    }
  });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places">
</script>
```

Comment: When I [google it](https://maps.google.de/maps?q=48+spottiswoode+residences,+spottiwood+park,+Singapore+088660&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGlLvt0u7JAhWCYA8KHfG1BGYQ_AUIBygB) the returned address is **48 Spottiswoode Park Road,Singapur 088660** , not **48 spottiswoode residences, spottiwood park, Singapore 088660**

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the full address in your request. The first part **48 spottiswoode residences, spottiwood park** is missing in

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sSingapore%2C%20088660&7sUS&8m2&1scountry&2sSingapore&9sen-US&callback=xdc._wo127a&token=117480

you need to url-encode that as well to get the correct location.